# Elisione in questi casi?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, orthography

I numeri possono  SEMPRE essere soggetti a elisione sia nella pronuncia che nello scritto davanti a parole  che iniziano per vocale?

Tipo:
Diciott'ore, vent'anni, ott'ore, quindic'anni.

Cosa prevede la grammatica italiana in questi casi?

Comment: È (purtroppo) comune in certa recente letteratura trovare *c’ho* o *quindic’anni* che vorrebbero riprodurre la pronuncia “legata”, con l'idea che *ci ho* e *quindici anni* farebbero pensare a una pronuncia “slegata” (idea che trovo bizzarra).

Answer (score 4):

L'*Italiano* di Serianni dice, parlando dei numeri cardinali (par. VI.10):

> I numeri polisillabici possono elidere la vocale finale davanti all'iniziale vocalica della parola seguente. Oggi ciò avviene solo in alcune locuzioni cristallizzate (come «a quattr'occhi») e col sostantivo *anni*: «Cent'anni di solitudine» [altri esempi con “vent'anni” e “mill'anni”]. Nei secoli scorsi il fenomeno era un po' più esteso: «son sett'ore» ([F.M. Piave, *La Traviata*]), «le sessant'onze della casa te le mangerai tu, fino all'ultimo grano» (Capuana, *Racconti*).

A titolo personale aggiungo che, degli esempi proposti nella domanda, “vent'anni” suona naturale, mentre gli altri molto meno (e in particolare “quindic'anni” dà l'idea di doversi pronunciare “quindikanni”).

Comment: Sì, io uso al massimo _vent'anni_